# Dplyr: How to recode groups that have frequency less than 1% into "other" category using only dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, pie-chart

I am looking for a method to do the following:
I have data:

```
group_name
A
A
..[50 A's]
B
B 
..[50 B's]
C [only 1]
```

I have possibly a lot of categories like C, and want to do a piechart. To make it convient for viewer, I need to recategorize groups so the less frequent values are recoded to "others" for plotting only. I want to do this using dplyr, something like:

```
dfd %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% recategorize(function(x) { if (x$n < 10) { "other" } else { x$category } }
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: There is a special function for summarizing by `n()`: `DF %>% count(category)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work,

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(group_name) %>% 
  mutate(new_group_name = ifelse(n()>10, group_name, 'others'))
```

then just use the new_group_name to do your summaries

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, after reading your code, I came up with answer that satisfies me:

```
summ <- dt  %>% group_by(group_name) %>% 
  mutate(groups_over10 = ifelse(n() > floor(nrow(.) * 0.01), as.character(group_name), "other")) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(groups_over10) %>% summarise(n=n())
pie(summ$n,labels = summ$groups_over10)
```

The trick is that you have to ungroup results of group_by and then group by newly computed variable. Thanks!